# How do you properly grant access to an ApiResource for a given client in Identity Server 4.0.3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, authorization, identityserver4

Previously we could define the following configuration, and it would work:

```
public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> GetApiScopes() =>
    new List<ApiScope>
    {
        new ApiScope(
            name: "Scope1",
            displayName: "scope1 description",
            userClaims: new[] { "claim1" }),
        new ApiScope(
            name: "Scope2",
            displayName: "scope2 description",
            userClaims: new[] { "claim2", "claim3", "claim4"}),
        new ApiScope(
            name: "Scope3",
            displayName: "scope3 description",
            userClaims: new[] { "claim5" }),
        new ApiScope(
            name: "Scope4",
            displayName: "scope4 description",
            userClaims: new[] { "claim6" })
    };
    
public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources() =>
    new List<ApiResource>
    {
        new ApiResource("MyApi", "MyApi description")
        {
            ApiSecrets = { new Secret("secret").Sha256() },
            Scopes =
            {
                "Scope1",
                "Scope2",
                "Scope3",
                "Scope4"
            }
        }
    };
    
public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients() =>
    new List<Client>
    {
        new Client
        {
            Enabled = true,
            ClientId = "client",
            ClientSecrets = "secret"
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,
            AllowOfflineAccess = true,
            AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Reference,
            RequireConsent = false,
            RequirePkce = false,
            UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh = true,
            RefreshTokenExpiration = TokenExpiration.Absolute,
            AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime = 123456,
            RefreshTokenUsage = TokenUsage.ReUse,
            AccessTokenLifetime = 600000,
            AllowedScopes = { "MyApi" }, // This previously worked, now it doesn't
        }
    };
```

But due to various changes, somewhat explained [here](https://leastprivilege.com/2020/06/18/resource-access-in-identityserver4-v4-and-going-forward/), you can no longer do the above, because `"MyApi"` written in `Client.AllowedScopes` is not a scope - in other words you can't request access to resources as you did before by supplying their name

Instead, to get the above working in Identity Server 4.0.3, you have to do the following hack, which I feel is terribly wrong, hence the question:

```
public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> GetApiScopes() =>
    new List<ApiScope>
    {
        new ApiScope(
            name: "Scope1",
            displayName: "scope1 description",
            userClaims: new[] { "claim1" }),
        new ApiScope(
            name: "Scope2",
            displayName: "scope2 description",
            userClaims: new[] { "claim2", "claim3", "claim4"}),
        new ApiScope(
            name: "Scope3",
            displayName: "scope3 description",
            userClaims: new[] { "claim5" }),
        new ApiScope(
            name: "Scope4",
            displayName: "scope4 description",
            userClaims: new[] { "claim6" }),
        // Wrapper
        new ApiScope(
            name: "MyApi",
            displayName: "",
            // Manually add all claims from above scopes. 
                        // If you end up in the future changing one of the above scopes's required claims,
                        // well, make sure you do the same here...
            userClaims: new[] { "claim1", "claim2", "claim3", "claim4", "claim5", "claim6"})        
    };
    
public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources() =>
    new List<ApiResource>
    {
        new ApiResource("MyApi", "MyApi description")
        {
            ApiSecrets = { new Secret("secret").Sha256() },
            Scopes =
            {
                "MyApi"
            }
        }
    };
    
public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients() =>
    new List<Client>
    {
        new Client
        {
            Enabled = true,
            ClientId = "client",
            ClientSecrets = "secret"
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,
            AllowOfflineAccess = true,
            AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Reference,
            RequireConsent = false,
            RequirePkce = false,
            UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh = true,
            RefreshTokenExpiration = TokenExpiration.Absolute,
            AbsoluteRefreshTokenLifetime = 123456,
            RefreshTokenUsage = TokenUsage.ReUse,
            AccessTokenLifetime = 600000,
                        // now works because we have a fake "MyApi" scope,
                        // encapsulating our previously well-defined structure of scopes
            AllowedScopes = { "MyApi" }, 
        }
    };
```

It makes zero sense to wrap a whole `ApiResource`'s scopes into a single scope and define all of the claims present in said scopes.

Could someone please shine the light upon this - what is the correct way of achieving what we were achieving in past versions of Identity Server4?

**EDIT:** Basically what I'm trying to ask is - how do you **require** that a specific resource be granted a specific set of scopes? (If any of them are not present in the token - invalidate it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that this worked before is because in previous versions the resource definition automatically included a scope with the same name.

Please note, MyApi is here the scope name, which is equal to the resource name.

```
AllowedScopes = { "MyApi" }
```

But the token contains the resource name as audience, which is quite confusing. As a result a client can access the resource if it has at least one scope that is part of the resource. Within the resource the scopes should be verified to make sure the client is authorized to use a sepcific part of the resource, e.g.:

```
services
    .AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("Scope1", p => p.RequireClaim("scope", "Scope1"));
```

It seems that in your case the client can access the entire resource regardless the specified scopes.

So what you should do is, verify the scopes in the resource and name the allowed scopes in the client definition:

```
AllowedScopes = { "Scope1", "Scope2", "Scope3", "Scope4" }
```

Or omit the line if all scopes are allowed. That will automatically include all allowed scopes.

---

Update based on the comments.

You can verify the scopes on receiving the bearer token in the api with something like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.JwtBearerEvents = new JwtBearerEvents
        {
            OnTokenValidated = async context =>
            {
                // To verify if required scopes are included:
                var requiredScopes = new List<string> { "scope1" , "scope2", "scope3", "scope4" };
                var foundScopes = context.Principal.Claims.Count(c => c.Type == "scope" && allowedScopes.Contains(c.Value));

                if (foundScopes != requiredScopes.Count)
                {
                    context.Fail("Invalid number of scopes");
                }
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, but some of your examples, specifically the AddPolicy example I believe to be incorrect. Why - a scope is not a claim. A scope is something, which can contain a list of claims tied to the specified scope. I think you should instead use the method `RequireScope` with your list of required scopes. But this introduces the next problem. How will you apply the policy on a global level, without hindering existing defined actions/controllers with defined access for specific policies? if you use `DefaultPolicy`, it'll only work for cases where you've supplied only [Authorize]

Comment: But for the other cases as mentioned, where you've defined already an action/endpoint with a [Authorize(SomePolicy)], the default policy will not be used. Furthermore, it makes no sense to even accept the token, when you **require** all listed scopes under the `ApiResource`. Is there a way to short-circuit the Jwt/Introspection Authentication handler, so that if the required scopes do not exist - simply treat it as an invalid access/reference token?

Comment: Please ignore the part about using `RequireScope`. Seems yours is the correct way to declare that intention in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: @SpiritBob IdentityServer will include all scopes as claims (claim type 'scope') in the access token. You can use RequireClaim("scope"), but if I'm not mistaken then RequireScope is equivalent. You can use [Authorize] to secure functionality that is part of the scope. Please note, the resource is a logical name and is not limited to one api per resource. When you have multiple api's where each api implements one or more scopes that are part of the resource, then it makes sense. Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52939428) for some more details about that.

Comment: @SpiritBob In addition, when I have _client1_ with `AllowedScopes = { "Scope1", "Scope2" }` and _client2_ with `AllowedScopes = { "Scope3", "Scope4" }` then both can access the resource, but you don't want _client1_ to access `Scope3` and `Scope4` functionality and vica versa restrict _client2_ to access `Scope1` and `Scope2` functionality.

Comment: From what I've gathered thanks to your given insight, is that in the end - an API should never validate scopes, instead - it should validate the claims of a user. What i mean by that is the following: Say `Scope1` encompasses `claim1`, `claim2`, `claim3`. We don't care if an access token coming to our API/resource has `Scope1`, but we do care if a specific operation they are doing, is possible. Knowing they have `Scope1` in no way helps us understand if that operation is possible. It only offers knowledge that those 3 claims are present in their token.

Comment: So, we'd rather just create a policy checking the claim we're interested in, that it matches our business rules, rather than making a policy to match if `Scope1` exists. I fail to find reason where you'd really need to validate scopes. I think those are more helpful to the end-user, to understand how much access their access token has, or to have a general idea of what kind of access they have with that access token. Do you agree?

Comment: @SpiritBob You should care, scopes are for _client authorization_, user claims for _user authorization_. Please note the difference. The api has to validate the client first and then the user. You'll find a reason when you open your resource for external clients that are allowed to access only specific parts of the resource. Also check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59654375). _Client authorization_ doesn't rule out _user authorization_. The _client_ is the means for a user to reach the resource, but it's the _user_ that has to be authorized to access the data.

Comment: How exactly are scopes for client authorization? If you want to authorize a specific client, just make a policy in regards to their `client_id` claim that it indeed confers to the one you had in mind. The question that you linked by the way ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59653267/controlling-client-access/59654375#59654375)) fully answers what I wanted to do - require that in order to access the given API/resource, you have to have not one, but ALL listed scopes (instead of using .Any, I'll just do a foreach and make sure every one is present)

Comment: @SpiritBob It wasn't clear to me that that was where you were after. I've updated the answer based on your last comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219848/discussion-between-spiritbob-and-ruard-van-elburg).